# Interfaz de usuario personalizada con java FX fxml

Tags: css, javafx, fxml, javafx-css

estoy creando un una interfaz de usuario personaliza utilizando java fxml y estilos css, antes de empezar mi proyectos hice el concepto de como queria que fuera mi interfaz , el problema es que cuando la eh implementado o mas bien la eh querido hacer pues no es como me esperaba , os paso un capura de lo que queria hacer , era unos botones en forma hexagonal con un distribucion mas o menos en cruz , pero en fxml pues eh echo usando elemento grid y botones junto con estilos css , pero el resultado no es el mismo que me me imagine, por eso aqui comparto el codigo de lo que eh realizado junto con el resultado y me gustaria saber si alguien pudiera darme otra solucion mas cercana a la de mi vison o si es posibleycon un poco de condigo. gracias

Aqui os paso lo que quiero obtener

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ahora esto es lo que eh podido hacer en fxml

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Seguidamente os paso el codigo en fxml y css

```
 <GridPane alignment="CENTER" prefWidth="600.0">
        <rowConstraints>
           <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="48.0" />
           <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="48.0" />
           <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="48.0" />
        </rowConstraints>
        <columnConstraints>
           <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
           <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
           <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
        </columnConstraints>
            <children>
                <Button prefHeight="70.0" prefWidth="80.0" styleClass="hexagon-button" text="Top" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />

                <Button prefHeight="70.0" prefWidth="80.0" styleClass="hexagon-button" text="Bottom" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />

                <Button prefHeight="70.0" prefWidth="80.0" styleClass="hexagon-button" text="Right" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />

                <Button prefHeight="70.0" prefWidth="80.0" styleClass="hexagon-button" text="Left" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            </children>
        </GridPane>
```

y despues el codigo css

```
    /* styles.css */
.hexagon-buttonhole {

    -fx-shape: "M 50 0 L 150 0 L 200 75 L 150 150 L 50 150 L 0 75 Z";
    -fx-background-color: #3498db; /* Color de relleno */
    -fx-border-color: #2980b9; /* Color del borde */
    -fx-border-width: 2; /* Ancho del borde */
    -fx-background-insets: 5; /* Margen interior para dar espacio al contenido */
    -fx-padding: 5; /* Margen exterior */
}
```

Aunque el texto de contenido no sea igual , lo que ahora mas me interesa es la distribucion y estructura de los botones , una solucion que se parezca mas a ala que habia pensado o talvez que le falta a mi condigo para que se parezca a lo que tenia pensado . gracias

Comment: [Aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72502727/2553194) tienes algo muy parecido a lo que quieres hacer, con más hexágonos y sin usar css. A priori no sería muy dificil adaptarlo a tus necesidades

Answer (score 0):

no te compliques. Usa el AnchorPane como base, luego agrega los elementos. Una vez dentro del contenedor, seleccionas uno de ellos y en la parte derecha del menu, hay un menu desplegable llamado **Layout**, la primera opcion te aparece una especie de cuadro pequeño donde podras establecer las distancias que tu quieres entre tu elemento y los bordes de la interfaz o del contenedor. Con ello resuelves el problema. Puedes activarlos todos o solo los que necesites. Puedes leer un poco sobre Constraints asi sabes como funciona mejor. Aca se llama AnchorPane Constraints

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]